# Is there a way to speed up making several API calls in Python?

Tags: python, api, discord.py

So I'm trying to code a bot that would update the roles of every user in a Discord server depending on their followers in a game. I have everyone's accounts linked in a database. My problem is that the server has about 500 users and that number is obviously going to increase as the server grows and for each user i need to:

1. Check whether the user is in my database.
2. If they are:

   - Get their game information (1 API request)
   - Update their Discord roles (7 requests)
3. If they are not

   - Update their Discord roles (7 requests)

Is there a way to reduce the amount of time required to go through all the members in that server? I'm currently using a for loop to loop through every user.

Answer (score 0):

Look into python's threading and queues, but fast and simple way will be to add [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor) and let it manage threads.
Wrap API request into a function and dispatch it into separate thread for each API call with `ThreadPoolExecutor.submit(f,...)`, it'll reduce total IO time by 'overlapping' times of individual calls.

Search for `ThreadPoolExecutor` examples, official docs are kinda lacking.